# How does the reset to level one work?

Tags: splatoon-2

In Splatoon 2, there is an option to reset to level 1 which is only possible after reaching level 99.

What happens to your gear and all other things collected? Can you use all weapons available at level 1? Do we get sea snail from level 1 or at level 30?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the reset dialogue with Judd, when you reset to ★1, you retain all of your gear, and all shops will remain available to you. You will also earn a sea snail when reaching level ★2, and every level after. ★1 is effectively just level 100.

[image: screenshot of Judd saying "Mrowr! (When you become level ★1, you'll keep all the gear and weapons you've collected so far!"]